# Can anyone tell me why this is not allowed?

Tags: integration, analysis

I tried to solve this problem.

[image]

Since ln(2) is a real number shouldn't the rule of integral(e^(ax))dx = [e^(ax)/a] be valid? I tried photo math and looked at the answer and the use integration by substitution.. I understand that approach I'm just curious why this doesn't work.

Comment: Who said it's not allowed?

Comment: The answer sheet says the correct answer should be 1/2..

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Ok, I’ll keep that in mind for next time!

Answer (score 3):

Because $e^{-\ln 2}$ is $\frac12$, not $2$.

Comment: And also $[f(x)]_0^1 = f(1) - f(0)$, not $f(0) - f(1)$, which takes care of the incorrect sign.

Comment: Thank you I just realised!